# JS Replace using the same phrase

Tags: javascript

How can I replace the exact string if it contains the same phrase?

```
var campaign = "sub.site.com";
campaign = campaign.replace("site.com", "campaign 1");
campaign = campaign.replace("sub.site.com", "campaign 2");
output = [{campaign: campaign}];
```

In this case, the output is `sub.campaign 1`. I want it to be `campaign 2`.

Comment: Replace with the longest match first?

Comment: That easy :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var campaign = "sub.site.com";
campaign = campaign.replace("site.com", "campaign 1");// campaign = 'sub.campaign 1'
campaign = campaign.replace("sub.site.com", "campaign 2"); //there is no instance of 'sub.site.com' in 'sub.campaign 1'
output = [{campaign: campaign}];
```

You are replacing the `site.com` bit from `sub.site.com` so it doesnt match

A cleaner way

```
var campaign = "sub.site.com";
if(campaign === 'site.com') {
   output = [{campaign: 'campaign 1'}];
}
else if(campaign === 'sub.site.com') {
   output = [{campaign: 'campaign 2'}];
}
```

or

```
switch("sub.site.com"){
  case 'site.com':
    output = [{campaign: 'campaign 1'}];
    break;
  case 'sub.site.com':
    output = [{campaign: 'campaign 2'}];
    break;
  default:      
}
```